# When naming hydrocarbons, when do you number the branch or double bond?

Tags: nomenclature, hydrocarbons

I have realized that not all chains and double bonds are numbered. I have noticed that up until 3 carbons in a chain, the double bond is not numbered, but I am not sure about the chain.

Comment: Numbering is only necessary where the un-numbered name is ambiguous. I'm not really sure what your question is.

Answer (score 2):

When there are 2 carbons in a chain, the double bond will be at the number 'one' position. Therefore it's not always mentioned in the naming.

For example:  Ethene
It can be written as 1-ethene or eth-1-ene. Since the position of the double bond can be at no other places than the first, the position in the naming you saw, wasn't mentioned.

When 3 or more carbons are present, the double bond can be between any 2 of the carbons, ie. either the first position or the second. (but-1-ene/butene or but-2-ene)

Position of double bonds and that of branches, must always be mentioned while naming organic compounds.

Comment: Prop-1-ene and prop-2-ene are the same.

Comment: Maybe you meant 4 Carbon -enes: (but-1-ene and but-2-ene)

Comment: Ahh yes sorry. I meant butene.